# What is the ratio of the range query in database or key-value store?

Tags: sql, mongodb, redis, key-value-store, database

Thank you for your interest in my question.

I wonder the ratio of the range query in database or key-value store.

Do the representative data management system like Redis and MongoDB support range query?

I would like to know what kinds of data management systems support range queries, and what benchmarks can simulate their typical workloads.

Comment: for Redis, range query are only supported for List and Sorted Set.

Comment: Thank Thomas for your comment.